# how to use import() or ensure splitting code in react with mobx

Tags: webpack-2, mobx

when use **react-router**, `getComponent` can asynchronous loading component, so sad that I can't find out how `getComponent` works. is there a normal way to asynchronous loading react component without use react-router? how to do it with mobx?